# Creating a 4-5 character column along the left margin in vim

Tags: vim

As a bit of context, I am considering making a plugin for vim that would inline specific debugging and/or profiling information on along the left margin (ideally left of the numbers column) which would need to be 4-5 characters wide. However, I cannot find any means to accomplish this. I've searched around, and the closest thing I can find is vimscript code for inserting signs in the sign column, but the sign column is fixed at 2 characters wide.

I've considered the possibility of making my own makeshift column (to the *right* of the numbers column, in the normally editable text area) and somehow marking it as readonly, but that doesn't seem possible either- from what I've read, the entire buffer must be readonly or not; you can't have just a portion as readonly.

For completeness here's an example. I would like to programmatically insert a 4-5 character column before some text (with numbers set)

```
1 Text buffer
2 with some
3 text
```

to make

```
My   1 Text buffer
own  2 with some
text 3 text
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Maybe something with opening up a vertical split to the left of your window and scrollbinding them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in feature for this is the *sign column*, but yes it is limited to two characters.

Depending on your use cases, it might be okay to enhance the signs with a tooltip popup ([`:help balloon-eval`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/debugger.txt.html#balloon-eval) explicitly mentions *This feature allows a debugger, or other external tool, to display dynamic information based on where the mouse is pointing.*), or maybe place the additional information in the [`quickfix`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix) or location list.

---

Modification of the actual buffer has many downsides (as it effectively prevents editing, and Vim's main purpose is just that). What some plugins do is showing a scratch (that is: unpersisted, unmodifiable) buffer in a vertical split, and setting the [`'scrollbind'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scrollbind%27) option so that its contents follow the original buffer. For an example, have a look at the [VCSCommand plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90), which uses this for annotating a buffer with commit information.